# Is there a way to search for all questions by a user who deleted their account?

Tags: support

I'm looking for a reference I provided in a comment to a question asked by a user who subsequently deleted their account. There were a lot of related questions so I can't remember which one it was by title.

The usual "search by user name" tool doesn't work if the user is deleted.

Is there another way?

Comment: Do you know their user id?

Comment: If you don't know their user ID, I may be able to figure it out for you.

Comment: For example, if you're looking for one of JCRM's posts that you commented on, this query would show all of them for you: https://data.stackexchange.com/space/query/edit/1384254

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know the user's ID, you can use the following Stack Exchange Data Explorer query to get a list of all their posts:

```
SELECT Id As [Post Link] FROM Posts WHERE OwnerDisplayName = 'user#'
```

You just have to replace `#` with the user ID.

Comment: Here's an example of a query I've used in the past: https://data.stackexchange.com/space/query/1292675